# Does the gas limit for AAVE transactions need to be so high?

Tags: ether, gas-limit, aave

There are two parts to the fee you pay for an Ethereum transaction - gwei and gas limit. Gwei is determined by how competitive (ie, congested) the Ethereum network is. As most people are aware, the amount of gwei required to get a transaction through has increased significantly, particularly in the last few months.

The other component of the fee is gas limit which is the maximum amount of gas that you're willing to spend on a particular transaction. It is estimated by the wallet you are using based on the complexity of the transaction youre trying to complete. So if you are just transferring eth, the gas limit will be lower than if you're interacting with a smart contract.

Anyway, my question relates AAVE. For some reason the gas limit suggested by my metamask wallet for AAVE transactions is really high, like almost 1,000,000 whereas most other smart contract transactions for other protocols are way way less, like 200k or 300k. I know it depends on the complexity of the transaction but the AAVE gas limit still seems ridiculously high. Does anyone know whether the gas limit for AAVE transactions can be reduced? Generally the advice is to only reduce gwei and not the gas limit. But when the gas limit is 930k, decreasing gwei only does so much.

Comment: Do you have an example transaction? The gas measures complexity of the contract. Defi contracts sometimes are really complex since they have to interact with other protocols.

Comment: I was sending 25$ of aave and fee is very high (lowest is around 60$ and highest was 121$) so it dont seem right that fees are more than amount you want to send